# Keyshot VR z-index

Tags: z-index

can anybody help with this problem?

I have embedded a Keyshot VR ( http://www.keyshot.com/vr/ ) clip into a web page (it's working fine in all browsers, so that's ok), the problem I'm having is that right next to the div containing the Keyshot clip is a sliding out menu bar. You can view it here http://pattonnz.businesscatalyst.com/unit#anchor-link-1  And the problem is that in Chrome the sliding out menu tabs are being covered up by the div containing the Keyshot clip div, in all other browsers the slide out tabs are at the top of the stack; all styles affecting the slide out tabs have a z-index of 1000 and all the styles affecting the Keyshot clip container have a z-index of 1.

Can anybody throw some light on this? I feel as though I've exhausted mu options. Is there anything in the KeyShotVR script itself that I can adjust to make it behave correctly? Or any other solution?

Thanks in advance
Grant

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position:relative;` on the iframe and you'll be good to go. Since you're not trying to absolutely position elements inside the iframe it's not necessary. It looks like you're controlling the iframe position with margins which is fine, but if you wanted to position the iframe with absolute positioning, you would make the overviewImg div  `position:relative;` and the internal div or iframe `position:absolute;` defining the top, left, bottom or right position.

Nice use of KeyShotVR by the way!